# Can I access to unseen facebook notifications?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications, facebook-fql

I'm using Facebook Graph Api and FQL.

I would like to access to unseen facebook notifications. Is it possible ?

I have tried to do something like this :

"me/notifications". I can get "unseen_count" in the summary block but how can I have the id of each "unseen" notification in order to find them ?

I know the "unread" but not the "unseen"...

Thansk in advance ;-)

Comment: You might be better of with using the [FQL notification table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/notification) instead – filter id with your user id and `is_unread`.

Comment: But is_unread is different from is_unseen ? no ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use FQL, you can easily get unread notifications:

Try running the following FQL query in your code or [test it here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20app_id,%20body_html,%20body_text,%20href%20FROM%20notification%20WHERE%20is_unread%20=%201%20AND%20recipient_id%20=%20me%28%29):

`SELECT app_id, body_html, body_text, href FROM notification WHERE is_unread = 1 AND recipient_id = me()`

You will need to ask for the `manage_notifications` permission for the call to work.